# Get a value of an interface using reflect

Tags: go, reflection, interface

I'm trying to get a value from [an interface](https://github.com/gambol99/go-marathon/blob/master/events.go#L107) (it should be a pointer to another struct, [see](https://github.com/gambol99/go-marathon/blob/master/events.go#L356)). 
Actually, I have to know the type of the pointer to access to the data it and it bother me. That's why I would like to use [reflect package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to do it better.

Actually, I can display the type using `reflect.TypeOf(event.Event).String()` but I don't understand how to change [this line](https://github.com/gambol99/go-marathon/blob/master/examples/events_sse_transport/main.go#L73) in the example without specifying with something like `.(*marathon.EventDeploymentStepSuccess)`

Comment: Go's type system doesn't support dynamically assigning a type

Comment: What do you want to change [here](https://github.com/gambol99/go-marathon/blob/master/examples/events_sse_transport/main.go#L73)? You want the same result but without using type assertion? Or you're looking for a different result?

Comment: @mkopriva I would like to do not write `(*marathon.EventDeploymentStepSuccess)` but something more dynamic with reflect. But I'm not even sure if it's possible

Comment: That's type assertion, `value.(type)`, so if I understand you correctly you want to access the `CurrentStep` field value without knowing the exact type? If yes, then you can use [relfect.Value.FieldByName](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) like this: https://play.golang.org/p/EXbTFXt7Iu.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I want, you solved my problem. Thank you @mkopriva

Comment: Please include your code in the question.